# Magento 2: Trouble adding product to cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart, redirect, session

Randomly, when I add something to cart from the product page, I am redirected to the cart page and told I have nothing in my cart. This doesn't happen consistently – if I refresh the cache (`magento cache:clean`), I'm able to add to cart again as normal (item is added to mini cart and I'm shown the confirmation message at the top of the product page).

Unfortunately, for no reason (that I can find), after using the site for a short period after the cache refresh, I run into the issue again!

I've disabled my custom theme and also the modules I've created, but it continues to happen.

I've checked the session, which appears to be blank on the times the cart fails to update.

Any help/advice/ideas where to look, would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**This may be due to corrupted database data.**

Have you tried to truncate, analyse and repair both `persistant_session` and `session` table?

*NOTE: This will empty all guest carts*

> It is important to always verify both the server and Magento logs `var/log`

**Computer / Browser Related**

I'm surprised that clearing Magento cache affected the issue positively, I would usually aim for the browser cache when it comes to session. This can also be a problem related to a specific computer having issues with cookie management. You may try with different computers and browsers.

**Core file restoration / Fresh Installation**

If this does not resolve the issue I would create a complete backup of the filsystem and copy the files from an original Magento installation over the Magento installation overriding all core files with the originals. This may resolve the issue in the case the problem would be caused by modified core files. On the other side if your actual installation relies on modified core files, these changes would be lost. Pay attention not to overwrite the .htaccess file with the default one. You may also try to install a fresh copy of the same Magento version elsewhere and test it to see if your are experiencing the same behavior.

**File System Ownership / Permissions**

This type of issue may arise when there is a file ownership issue. As Magento 2 maintenance can be done via command line, some ownership issues may appear if the wrong user or root was used to execute the maintenance script. This is a common problem among Magento 2 developers/store managers.

File permissions can also prevent Magento from reading/writing files in some folders therefore preventing further script execution. It is important to evaluate each folder specifically while maintaining the balance between security and flexibility and to never set the file permission to 777.

You may find useful this official [Magento guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html) regarding the subject.

**Server Software / Hardware**

If the issue persist, we may think of a php or server misconfiguration, or even a hardware failure.

Comment: Many thanks for you your response. To test the issue, I installed a new 'clean' version of M2. The problem also exists on the clean version too – it tends to just happen when trying to add configurable products.

Comment: As you installed a fresh M2 version I would suggest to observe these database tables: _`quote`_, _`quote_item`_ and _`quote_item_option`_ then add products to cart. The tables should reflect the added products and you may be able to notice if something is not registered as it should. If everything end up looking fine in the database it would suggest either a Magento 2 bug or a server misconfig causing cookie/session issues. **May I know which Magento and php version are you currently using?**
**Something also important, when intalling Magento did you chose file or database session storage?**

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at the DB.

I'm currently using:
PHP 7.0.10 and 
Magento ver. 2.1.2. I'm not sure what session storage I chose. Is there a way to check now?

Comment: I see that you are using the latest Magento 2 version and a stable php version. Yes, the easiest way to verify is by looking at the `session` variable in _`app/etc/env.php`_ or if the _`var/session`_ folder isn't empty then you are using the file system, otherwise the session table is used. It is recommanded to use the DB as it can store more sessions and comes with multiple advantages. **Thinking about the Page Cache, have you tried disabling it?** Without assumption, it is important to test the installation with different computers/browsers. It is often the source of this type of issues.

Comment: `app/etc/env.php ` is `session => array ( 'save' => 'files' )`. I don't seem to have the var/session folder. I have all caches enabled except for full page cache, I disabled that as it was slowing me down whilst developing.

Comment: You should have a _`var/session`_ folder as it is there even if Magento as been installed with the `'files'` setting. I'm thinking that this might be related but if the folder does not exist and there is also a permission issue preventing Magento to write the files, then nothing should be added to cart... I would create a _`var/session`_ folder with `770` permissions and set _`var`_ to `755`. I would recommand switching the session variable inside _`app/etc/env.php`_ to **`'db'`** for database. This will already prevent any file system error from interfering and is way better on the long run.

Comment: Interesting... I definitely don't have the `var/session` folder and noticed on the M2 site (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/sessions.html) that I should also have a 'save_path' => '/var/www/session', in the `env.php file` (which I do not).

Comment: I am using database session storage and do not have the _`var/www/session`_ folder. This might be it, I don't know Magento session system deeply but it is possible that Magento uses both _`/var/www/session`_ and _`var/session`_ for frontend sessions. Then the error would show up only when it has to use the second folder for specific session storage functions and the missing folder and file permission issue would prevent it to complete its execution. In this case I would assume that _`var/log/exception.log`_ contains something. I hope that this will resolve your issue, comments are piling up.

Comment: @Mitch7663 Please let me know if you were able to solve the problem with any of the provided suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I'm sorry to read that, in this case you might try to switch php version as some subversions contain specific bug. I would recommand copying the installation on an other physical server for testing purposes and see if the issue persists. If it does, it would confirm that it is a software problem. You may temporarily try to use the Magento default .htaccess and also load the default php.ini file with of course the necessary php extensions added without forgetting to set higher values for max_execution_time and memory_limit (Backup the filesystem and database first).